# How to convert int 64 to int 32 with avx (but without avx-512)

Tags: simd, sse, avx

I'd like to convert / pack a register of 4 longs (64 bits) to 4 ints (32 bits). In other words to convert a __m256i of int64 to a __m128i of int32.

I don't have avx-512 at my disposal so the intrisic:

```
__m256i n;
__m128i r128i = _mm256_cvtepi64_epi32( n );
```

is not available for me. Any alternatives better than the ones below?

**loosing vectorization:**

```
__m256i n;
alignas(32) int64_t temp[4];
_mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)temp, n);
int32_t a = (int32_t)temp[0];
int32_t b = (int32_t)temp[1];
int32_t c = (int32_t)temp[2];
int32_t d = (int32_t)temp[3];
__m128i r128i = _mm_set_epi32(a, b, c, d);
```

**this packs into 16bits integer instead of 32bits**

```
__m128i lo_lane = _mm256_castsi256_si128(n);
__m128i hi_lane = _mm256_extracti128_si256(n, 1);
__m128i r128i = _mm_packus_epi32(lo_lane, hi_lane);
```

Comment: How did you generate the `__m256i` values? Are you able to re-arrange two consecutive results to `{a0, a1, a4, a5}` and `{a2, a3, a6, a7}`?

Comment: @chtz "__m256i" stores the pixel values of a Mandelbrot fractal pattern and needs to be converted to a int32_t pixel buffer. (working on this: https://youtu.be/x9Scb5Mku1g?t=2928 to learn simd)

Comment: Mandelbrot doesn't need an interaction between elements, so you could probably use pairs of `__m256i` vectors with an arrangement of 64-bit elements that let you just use an in-lane `_mm256_shuffle_ps` to get the final result in order, with the four elements from the 2x2 low halves going into the low half of the result, then the high halves, if that's what @chtz had in mind.

Comment: Exactly, @PeterCordes (I was not going to watch the video -- I did not think that code-as-image could be topped ...)

Comment: @chtz: Yeah, me neither.  A video without separate code / text links seems like one of the worst ways to present a tutorial, making skimming and searching impossible.  Fortunately the actual SO question inspired by it is well asked.  (And SIMD Mandelbrot in general has been asked about before, with problems like whether you keep running a whole vector of elements until the last one escapes or reaches max iterations, or until the first escapes.  i.e. how to make good use of your execution units.  Simplest, and ok for non-huge max iter counts, is to use a fixed layout).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So just truncation, not signed (or unsigned) saturation?  (I asked because AVX-512 provides [signed and unsigned saturation versions](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovqd:vpmovsqd:vpmovusqd), as well as truncation.  The non-AVX512 packs like `_mm_packus_epi32` (`packusdw`) you were using always do saturation, you have to use plain shuffle instructions if you want packing with truncation before AVX-512.  But if either is fine because the upper half is known zero, then yeah the pack instructions can be useful.)

---

#### Single vector `__m256i` -> `__m128i`

For a single vector, producing a narrower output, you could use `vextracti128` with `vshufps` to pack a single `__m256i` into a `__m128i`. Before AVX-512, `vshufps` is one of the only 2-input shuffles that has any control input, not just a fixed interleave for example.

In C with intrinsics, you'd need `_mm_castsi128_ps` and back to keep the compiler happy using `_mm_shuffle_ps` on integer vectors, but modern CPUs don't have bypass delays for using FP shuffles between integer SIMD instructions.  Or if you're just going to store it, you can leave the result as `__m128` and use `_mm_store_ps((float*)p, vec);`  (And yes it's still strict-aliasing safe to cast integer pointers to `float*` because the deref happens inside the intrinsic, not in pure C).

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m128 cvtepi64_epi32_avx(__m256i v)
{
   __m256 vf = _mm256_castsi256_ps( v );      // free
   __m128 hi = _mm256_extractf128_ps(vf, 1);  // vextractf128
   __m128 lo = _mm256_castps256_ps128( vf );  // also free
   // take the bottom 32 bits of each 64-bit chunk in lo and hi
   __m128 packed = _mm_shuffle_ps(lo, hi, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));  // shufps
   //return _mm_castps_si128(packed);  // if you want
   return packed;
}
```

This is 2 shuffles per 128-bit of output data.  We can do better: 2 shuffles per 256-bit of output data.  (Or even just 1 if we can have our input arranged nicely).

---

#### 2x `__m256i` inputs producing a `__m256i` output

Fortunately clang spotted a better optimization than I did.  I thought of 2x `vpermd` + `vpblendd` could do it, shuffling the low32 of each element in one vector to the bottom lane, or top lane in the other.  (With a `set_epi32(6,4,2,0,  6,4,2,0)` shuffle control).

But clang optimized that into `vshufps` to get all the elements we want into one vector, then `vpermpd` (equivalent to `vpermq`) to get them into the correct order.  (This is generally a good strategy, and I should have thought of that myself. :P  Again, it's taking advantage of `vshufps` as a 2-input shuffle.)

Translating that back into intrinsics, we get code that will compile to that efficient asm for GCC or other compilers ([**Godbolt compiler explorer** for this and the original](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYgkAdlIAB1QFQlsGZzcPPVj4mwFffyCWUPCuKMtMa0ShAiZiAmT3Ty4LTCtMhnLKgmzAkLCJADYLCqqa1PqFAfa/Trzurh6ASgtUV2Jkdg4AUgAmAGY/ZDcsAGo1rcc8FhY/AmI/ADoEY%2Bw1jQBBJ%2BfTFi4NgA4D5AA3AiYaJ4HqSYzAvBbDbGJj/VRcCAfDYAVh6eAO/1mbzWEQAQm8DkTkWjMVQjlsACIHYznVE9YyiUbxenGaIKCCYg7YrZ4on8g4AekFByoxEwmEJxNpX1%2BCAxx2ptJYrMwqiuTGsVFlbI5/yopAOXB5fKFIv%2Bao1WtlUppMp%2BB1oqApSrpaMZTFG7NZ7NlnP13OOpuFBzECmdYoltpDFQA1pgDgQEAngqgCEQWAdoQdgoQFAdUOTMJqEAcwQBaXMEP4IVwMWMHPyO52GdAHeW2j6yg7RTXxtuKmnnYwKWtUKj0XUQJ2G%2BWG4wAWQXxiEAAk5AAxDfebAQDaGjSG/cHDSzE1EkOj1xUdnRwXighLBhDlger0KEd4P295D9k22h8nx7PtMHQIMcQiakiRxF4SXRYDfzBIhoSRWl6QxJh5zQtEMWCbEXlxAkXgFENgGIJhgkTZMsw2StCGbAB3dsxAtfNCzLSQ6OrRpMDYQR80uZ0BATC1rBITtsJ6P5UDyCYBypF9WSvcdJ3ZJE3QZJkCBZd01KYeZbQFIzjJM0zjOVVktJ0hk1Lw%2BclxXdctx3PdSEPfdT3/AjiP5ENxXLSpyKMBNezwYg2PJaEuIOHi%2BO0g4GMIUt/miMIWGiNsIBITFUuIFgAEdG3JABPRYEsMAh8OeAU4LbEgsHFeTXRVXS0tcIFJFUME2XQdSWs0z0CHZHqIDQWT/HQeYaQctdN23XctlIeoPLPcCfKJQDiGfCz3S0jLP3pLLiAa0CvNeSCYNeF4Qz2QxgALaIbAuAAvTB8yTPABMEFtMTCYqDnwccwkYasIFbHNMHTMJZgOUZyKBYBireEM02TYhpPSugwnzdABDADgCDeOCMR/WMkNQaFjBocKCFhKH0oIVD%2BowrDmZzKrCLvAG8YJg4WCYeMqM%2B2GKhscwMZBehwpFoLgEaf7cYOAAqBiSCUJWEqSqimAIG5DLQBhRjtNnlJdRT3SUWnIRQvoDmkA5j0PIlbftx2zpIkVlInFNUaOdbQzNnabLaoF/kqb5VEp62NjBw1lPd/lKMHIO2RDzAw%2BICOo5BFDgjjscE42yGgJT4J6AYdAIRzmPMJzA9gi4RuuA0FvTzW87KTeDh5loTgUV4TwOC0UhUE4RxYcWZYE02LYeFIAhNG7%2BZYxALYthuNfN637e%2Bl7jhJF4FgJBb0hB%2BH0eOF4BQQEPBeh%2B70g4FgJAxslsJyEoV%2BsfCZBbqML4ND1BoLQIE4VKDBEXqQXMzBiDFU4HPMacUADyDBaBwPvqQLA/MjDiAwfgcUpRWKQLVCUdqqw56XEaJA2geBgjkVgc4LAkCrhnHgQ/CcTBgAKAAGp4EwAxJBqVB5z34IIEQYh2BSBkIIRQKh1AYN0PUAwRgQCmEZPoWh19IDzFQI9RI18ODliQVsA45Z%2BbLHuFSBAnoGKNFoFfHipQ7AQAcEMOopAfATFyPkNIcQEgCDcb4jIiQOjeOmA0JoZQxiBJGI45orQqihK6AUfobQYmpMSV45JEh5jhiWCsPQVwJRsJ7n3AekCL6qG%2BD0csYI/jKPul8G4GgbhcAOBARwhpcCEGyjPeoBxnCYylkcbYxpeB3y0GeUgK814b23vMteu9OAH1PhUzgV8b7z0XvMJ%2BiAUAyTfmQCgo0DnfxQMARu%2B5gGgOvhACBGDoGVHQQgmSyDUHoOHlgu6uDPlhRKDYIhGCSHIDIWw8gggqEYJoXQp5jDVjDxYUfbg7CDBcN4fwwRjAwWiOEKIcQUicWyLUJA3Q%2B4GmqLMBo4IWiIA6L0QIAxRiTFmMqMgSxlJrEKFsbQexET/mJHsBXdJnicjZPqOkfxSQXC1CCZKpJUwUnFCcS0aJ0rhh8uVQk8YoqFV6FGGktV7j9WZJ1T440Cx8mSPnuKchD89791WRgyp1TamSAOMAX%2BRouA3A2O0zpBxulEHRn0w0gzDkjOhLMcZ2zl6r3XgshZ%2BhlnlKdesiwmyJlLyTRwDYh9j6HjPrwC%2B0b75TItOFAVkggA%3D)):

```
// 2x 256 -> 1x 256-bit result
__m256i pack64to32(__m256i a, __m256i b)
{
    // grab the 32-bit low halves of 64-bit elements into one vector
   __m256 combined = _mm256_shuffle_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(a),
                                       _mm256_castsi256_ps(b), _MM_SHUFFLE(2,0,2,0));
    // {b3,b2, a3,a2 | b1,b0, a1,a0}  from high to low

    // re-arrange pairs of 32-bit elements with vpermpd (or vpermq if you want)
    __m256d ordered = _mm256_permute4x64_pd(_mm256_castps_pd(combined), _MM_SHUFFLE(3,1,2,0));
    return _mm256_castpd_si256(ordered);
}
```

It compiles to just 2 instructions with immediate shuffle controls, no vector constants.  The source looks verbose but it's mostly just casts to keep the compiler happy about types.

```
# clang -O3 -march=haswell
pack64to32:                             # @pack64to32
        vshufps ymm0, ymm0, ymm1, 136           # ymm0 = ymm0[0,2],ymm1[0,2],ymm0[4,6],ymm1[4,6]
        vpermpd ymm0, ymm0, 216                 # ymm0 = ymm0[0,2,1,3]
        ret
```

---

##### With input reordering to avoid lane-crossing: one `vshufps`

If you can arrange pairs of input vectors so they have 64-bit elements in `{a0, a1 | a4, a5}` and `{a2, a3 | a6, a7}` order, you only need an in-lane shuffle: the low 4x 32-bit elements come from the low halves of each 256-bit input, etc.  You can get the job done with one `_mm256_shuffle_ps`.  (Exactly as above, not needing the `_mm256_permute4x64_pd`).  Credit to @chtz in comments under the question for this suggestion.

Mandelbrot doesn't need an interaction between elements, so you could probably use pairs of `__m256i` vectors with that arrangement of 64-bit elements.

If you're starting with an unrolled loop with something like `{0,1,2,3}` and `{4,5,6,7}` and using `_mm256_add_epi64` with `set1_epi64(8)` to increment, you could instead start with `{0,1,4,5}` and `{2,3,6,7}` and everything should work identically.  (Unless you're doing something else where it matters what order your elements are in?)

---

#### Asm vs. intrinsic names

Consult [Intel's intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2&text=shufps&expand=6375) to search by asm mnemonic; they're shorter to type and easier to think about in terms of what the machine can actually do, and asm mnemonics are needed for looking up performance in https://uops.info/table.html / https://agner.org/optimize/

Comment: Truncation is fine although I'd be interested to know if there are solutions for saturation for learning purposes (even if it involves avx-512)

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm looking for a solution with intrinsic. When you say vshufps are you suggesting to use _mm256_shuffle_epi8? You can't shuffle across the 128bits lane (_mm256_castsi256_si128( _mm256_shuffle_epi8 (_n, _mm256_set_epi8(...,27,26,25,24,19,18,17,16,11,10,9,8,3,2,1,0)) ); won't work as expected) so it needs extra work to pack my 2 int32s in each __m128i lane and then _mm_or_si128 the two registers.

Comment: @arkan: [Intel's intrinsic finder lets you search by asm mnemonic](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2&text=shufps&expand=6375).  `...ps` mnemonics are always `..._ps` intrinsics.  This is `_mm256_shuffle_ps`.  (And yes, to keep a C compiler happy you'd have to use `_mm256_cast...` intriniscs to use an FP shuffle on integer data.)  However, like I said, you don't actually want `vshufps`.

Comment: @arkan: unless you're just packing a single `__m256i` down to one `__m128i`, not doing 2x 256-bit vectors -> 1x 256-bit vector.

Comment: @arkan: Updated with intrinsics.  (And a better strategy for 2x __m256i  -> __m256i that does use `_mm256_shuffle_ps`).

Comment: @arkan: AVX-512 provides signed or unsigned saturation as well as truncation, documented in the same entry of the instruction-set manual as the truncating form you already found.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovqd:vpmovsqd:vpmovusqd.  `_mm256_cvtusepi64_epi32` is unsigned saturation, `_mm256_cvtsepi64_epi32` is signed.  (Interestingly, AVX-512 conversions are also available for narrowing by more than a factor of 2, e.g. even qword -> byte in one step, with all 3 choices of saturation/truncation available for every size combo.)